# How does async call knows when to start completed event in new thread or use caller thread

Tags: c#, silverlight, asynchronous

Let's say we have a service `TestService` with `DoWork` method. On the client, it will generate `DoWorkCompleted` and `DoWorkAsync` methods.

This is my observation if you call `DoWorkAsync` from UI thread, `DoWorkCompleted` will be executed on UI thread as expected.

But if I start `BackgroundWorker` and call service `DoWorkAsync` from it then `DoWorkCompleted` is executed on new thread other than caller thread. Example:

1. Start `BackgroundWorker` instance <-
   From UI Thread
2. Worker `DoWork` method gets executed
   <- Thread 2
3. Call to service `DoWorkAsync` from
   worker `DoWork` <- From thread 2
4. Service runs and `DoWorkCompleted`
   gets executed <-- Thread 3
5. Worker `DoWorkCompleted` gets
   executed <- UI thread

How does Service client know when to start new thread and when to post it back to caller thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with the availability of a [`SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) on the thread. In Windows Forms, I assume Silverlight is the same, when you start an application the main thread that will become the UI thread is provided with a [`SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) that allows calls to be marshaled back to the UI thread.

In your first scenario, since you call `DoWorkAsync` from a thread with a synchronization context available the `DoWorkCompleted` is marshaled back to the initial thread.

In your second scenario you are on a thread pool thread without a synchronization context so the `DoWorkCompleted` is not marshaled back to the initial thread.

Comment: So basicly DoWorkAsync implementation look For SynchronizationContext and if it is not found run completed from new thread

Comment: Yes, I believe it's basically that. You can use `SynchronizationContext.Current` to explicitly check the availability of the context.